# Oracle regexp_like - only certain characters, numbers and one symbol

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, preg-match

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM dual
WHERE regexp_like ('ABC-123', '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$');
```

I would like to use Oracle's regexp_like to only allow the following:

1. A to Z, uppercase and lowercase.
2. All numbers.
3. Symbol **-**

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: @andreas777: Try `WHERE regexp_like ('ABC-123', '^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to match a hyphen, the ones inbetween `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9` are not literal hyphens, they are functional characters defining a range.

You need to add a hyphen to the end of the `[...]`:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$
           ^
```

To avoid empty matches, use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$
             ^
```